# Event for user enable "Download from unknown sources" From Settings

Tags: android

I need to get notified when the user enable the "Download unknown sources from Setting". is this possible?

Cheers

Comment: No. That is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately Android doesn't send anything when the user changes the value of `Unknown Sources` configuration. But you can register an observer class that gets callbacks when data identified by a given content URI changes.

You need to create the `ContentObserver`:

```
ContentObserver observer = new ContentObserver(null) {
    @Override
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
        super.onChange(selfChange);

        int enabled = Settings.System.getInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.INSTALL_NON_MARKET_APPS, 0);
        Log.d(TAG "onChange " + String.valueOf(enabled != 0));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean deliverSelfNotifications() {
        return true;
    }
};
```

Then you can register it with this code:

```
Uri setting = Settings.System.getUriFor(Settings.Secure.INSTALL_NON_MARKET_APPS);
getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(setting, false, observer);
```

When done you can unregister the content observer:

```
getContentResolver().unregisterContentObserver(observer);
```

Comment: Thanks , it worked out of the box. just one more question. If I want a to keep the Content observer alive in the Background after my app is killed in order to react to the change, will it have a bad performance implications?  Thanks again for the quick answer

Comment: To keep the content observer in background you need to create a long-running service. This consumes some CPU or RAM, and obviously the performances are worse than a broadcast receiver that it's triggered only when an intent is received. But unfortunately Android doesn't send an intent when that settings change, so there isn't many alternative.